# Как отредактировать переменную Local Storage?

Tags: json, javascript

Работаю с Local Storage. Создал переменную и записал в неё json.

Как можно редактировать уже имеющийся local storage?
Как добавить переменную в json, как удалить переменную из json в Local Storage?

Пример: У меня есть `site={"name":"Denis"};`. Мне нужно добавить `"family":"Balash"`, чтобы переменная была `site={"name":"Denis","family":"Balash"}`.

Comment: Если вас не затруднит, поделитесь, что вы сделали.

Comment: Я создал переменную site в local storage и записал в неё json: {"name":"Denis"}. Теперь я хочу дописать в переменную site "family":"Yirnic". Т.е чтобы было так : {"name":"Denis","family":"Yirnic"}

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage

Comment: Я что-то не нашёл там пример кода для редактирование переменной в local storage?!

Comment: всё равно непонятно:

    var obj = {"family":"Yirnic"};
    obj["name"] = site["name"];
    site = obj;

примерно так? или что?

Comment: Проще говоря, у меня есть site={"name":"Denis"};  Мне нужно добавить в "family":"Balash". Т.е. чтобы переменная site={"name":"Denis","family":"Balash"}

Comment: js динамический язык - просто сделайте  site["family"] = "Balash";

Comment: Но тогда у меня это в localStorage не запишется. Хотя можно перезаписать localStorage

Answer (score 3):

1. Считать переменную из localStorage
2. Добавить поле в переменную в JavaScript
3. Записать переменную в localStorage

Редактировать значение в localStorage без извлечения в переменную [невозможно](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-localstorage-attribute).